# How to return result of ADD AND in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that will sum values in a for loop.

I've tried:

```
def get_total_items(self):
    return totalnum = totalnum + item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values()
```

I am getting a syntax error, however I am unsure why as this seems correct to me.

Comment: I'm assuming `self.cart` is a `dict`, are the values *also* `dicts`?

Comment: are you trying to return the sum of the list

Comment: How is your cart defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is [the `sum` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with a generator expression. A generator expression is similar to the loop you were trying for, but bounded by parentheses (which can be the same as the call parens when it's the only argument, as with `sum`):

```
def get_total_items(self):
    return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
```

Note that `totalnum` is never assigned (you can't assign as part of a `return`), but it doesn't have to be; the value from `sum` is returned directly without storing it in a named variable at all.

If `totalnum` is some existing global that must be updated, you'll need to split this into three lines, one to declare `totalnum` a global (so it doesn't become a local due to being assigned), one to increment `totalnum`, one to `return` it:

```
def get_total_items(self):
    global totalnum
    totalnum += sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
    return totalnum
```

Comment: Ah, thankyou.totalnum is not a global, I was just trying to assign it as part of return. I am trying to use sum with item['quantity'] but it is always returning 0, and it should be returning at least one.

Comment: @JakeRankin: If it's always returning zero, `self.cart` is either empty, all the quantities are zero, or you somehow managed to have negative quantities that cancel out the positive quantities. Try a loop: `for item in self.cart.values(): print(item['quantity'])`; I suspect you'll find one of those to be the case (the less likely possibility is that the variable you're checking was initialized to zero, you're getting an exception here, e.g. because some `item` doesn't even have a `quantity`, and you're catching and ignoring the exception, then seeing the unmodified zero).

Answer (score 2):

According to [[Python 3]: The *return* statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return):

> **return_stmt** ::=  "return" [[expression_list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression-list)]

`totalnum = totalnum + item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values()` is not an expression but a statement, hence the *SynraxError*.

One way of doing it, is using [[Python 3]: **sum**(*iterable[, start]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```py
def get_total_items(self):
    return sum(item["quantity"] for item in self.cart.values())
```

The "old style" approach:

```py
def get_total_items(self):
    totalnum = 0
    for item in self.cart.values():
        totalnum += item["quantity"] 
    return totalnum
```

Comment: `sum` is not exactly "new style"; it's been around since Python 2.3, with generator expressions being added in 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

Use existing `sum()` function.

```
sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
```

Or, if you need a starting value:

```
sum((item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values()), 1000.0) #start summing with 1000.0
```

If you absolutely must implement it yourself:

```
def get_total_items(self):
    totalnum = 0
    for item in self.cart.values():
        totalnum += item['quantity'] 
    return totalnum
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you do it like this:

```
def get_total_items(self):
    for item in self.cart.values():
        totalnum += item['quantity']
    return totalnum
```

Comment: Along with being (typically) slower than `sum`, this is guaranteed to die with an `UnboundLocalError`; you'd need to add either `global totalnum` or `totalnum = 0` at the top of the function to use a global variable of that name or initialize a local of that name respectively.